# Setting a store state on app mount in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, redux, react-redux

This is my code:

UI

```
export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(p) {
        super(p);
        this.state = {user: null};
    }

    setUser = () => {
        const {uid} = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        firebase.database().ref('Users').child(uid).on('value', r => {
            const user = r.val();
            this.setState({user: user});
            this.props.onLoad(this.state.user); // This is the problem
        });
    };

    componentWillMount() {
        if (firebase.auth().currentUser) {
            this.setUser();
        }
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async () => {
            if (!firebase.auth().currentUser) {
                return null;
            }
            this.setUser();
        });
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Nav/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Container

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({user: state.user});
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    onLoad(user) {
        dispatch(setUser(user))
    }
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

So what I'm trying to do is set a store as soon as the component mounts. And it works until a change is made in this app. If I change the data in the database the data updates in my app with no problem.

If I try to run this:

container:

```
import {setLevel} from "../../../../../actions";
import LevelSelectUI from '../../../ui/mainUI/levelSelectUI/LevelSelectUI';

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
    user: props.user
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    onLevelChange(uid, value) {
        dispatch(setLevel(uid, value));
    }
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LevelSelectUI)
```

UI

```
export default ({user = {}, onLevelChange = f => f}) => {
    const lvls = [{
        db: 'Podstawówka',
        text: 'PODSTAWOWA',
    }, {
        db: 'Gimnazjum',
        text: 'GIMNAZJALNA',
    }, {
        db: 'Liceum',
        text: 'ŚREDNIA',
    }];
    let options = [];
    if (!user.level) {
        options.push(<option key={options.length} value={null}>WYBIERZ POZIOM</option>)
    }
    options = options.concat(lvls.map((lvl, i) => {
        return (
            <option key={(i + 1) * 2} value={lvl.db}>{`SZKOŁA ${lvl.text}`}</option>
        )
    }));
    return (
        <select value={user.level}
                onChange={e => onLevelChange(e.target.value)}>
            {/*onChange={(e) => console.log(e.target.value)}>*/}
            {options.map(opt => opt)}
        </select>
    )
}
```

action:

```
export const setLevel = (value = '') => ({
    type: C.SET_LEVEL,
    payload: value,
});
```

reducer:

```
export const level = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case C.SET_LEVEL:
            return firebase.database().ref('Users').child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).child('level').set(action.payload).catch(e => console.log(e));
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

And if I run the above code I get this error:

> Error: You may not call store.getState() while the reducer is executing. The reducer has already received the state as an argument. Pass it down from the top reducer instead of reading it from the store.
>
> onLoad
>   src/AppContainer.jsx:8

```
   5 | const mapStateToProps = state => ({user: state.user});
   6 | const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
   7 |     onLoad(user) {
>  8 |         dispatch(setUser(user))
   9 |     }
  10 | });
  11 |
```

> App/_this.setUser/<
>   src/AppUI.jsx:38

```
  35 |         //         else this.setState({assignedWork: undefined});
  36 |         //     });
  37 |         // }
> 38 |         this.props.onLoad(this.state.user);
     | ^  39 |     });
  40 | };
  41 |
```

So I'm assuming my way of doing it is just wrong. But how can I set the state to equal the data in the databse? I tried doing it in store initialization, but it just errored out.

Comment: You should not be using ```firebase.database().ref('Users').child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).child('level').set(action.payload).catch(e => console.log(e));``` within reducers

Comment: So just put it into an action?

Comment: yeah, put it within action creator (thunk) and just save its result in reducer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up removing the the reducers and actions and just did this:

container:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
    user: props.user
});

const mapDispatchToProps = () => ({
    onLevelChange(value) {
        firebase.database().ref('Users').child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).child('level').set(value).catch(e => console.log(e));
    }
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LevelSelectUI)
```

UI:

```
export default ({user = {}, onLevelChange = f => f}) => {
    const lvls = [{
        db: 'Podstawówka',
        text: 'PODSTAWOWA',
    }, {
        db: 'Gimnazjum',
        text: 'GIMNAZJALNA',
    }, {
        db: 'Liceum',
        text: 'ŚREDNIA',
    }];
    let options = [];
    if (!user.level) {
        options.push(<option key={options.length} value={null}>WYBIERZ POZIOM</option>)
    }
    options = options.concat(lvls.map((lvl, i) => {
        return (
            <option key={(i + 1) * 2} value={lvl.db}>{`SZKOŁA ${lvl.text}`}</option>
        )
    }));
    return (
        <select value={user.level}
                onChange={e => onLevelChange(e.target.value)}>
            {/*onChange={(e) => console.log(e.target.value)}>*/}
            {options.map(opt => opt)}
        </select>
    )
}
```

Thanks [Manjeet Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5098308/manjeet-singh) for the leed